# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class ClassName

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a linked structure using arrays.

```
public class LinkedArray <E extends Comparable<E>>{
private Node<E>[] array;
private int head;
private int size = 0; 
private int capacity;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public LinkedArray (){
    capacity = 10;
    array= (Node<E>[]) new Object[capacity];
    head = -1;
    size = 0;
}
}
```

It has inner node class

```
private static class Node<T>{
    protected T data = null;
    protected int next = -1;
}
```

I get the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [LinkedArray$Node; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [LinkedArray$Node; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

For the line

```
array = (Node<E>[]) new Object[capacity];
```

What is the reason? How can I create a Node array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to create a `Object[]` and then cast it (which won't work since `Object` is not a subclass of `Node`), just use

```
array = new Node[capacity];
```

Comment: but when I use this how will it know which generic type will be used in Node?

Comment: @zibidigonzales 
Statements like
`LinkedArray<Integer> la = new LinkedArray<>();`
and
`new LinkedArray<Integer>() // anonymous object`
will define the generic type to use.

Answer (score 0):

Object class can't be cast to Node class. You can create No like below:
Node[] array = new Node[5];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).